# Can I add classes to individual menu links?

Tags: theming, navigation, 10

I am using the main menu /admin/structure/menu/manage/main

There are a couple of links that I want to display only in mobile devices, and then also another couple of links that I want to display only in laptop devices. Can I do this without needing two separate menus? I guess one way would be to attach a css class to the relevant links but looking at /admin/structure/menu/item/1/edit there is no option to add classes to a menu link in the menu UI.

I don't want to use CSS nth-child because if in future the menu is edited / reordered then any nth-child rules will get messed up.

So can anyone tell me how to add an option to add classes to individual menu links in the menu UI - and / or some alternative route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Menu Link Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes) contrib module adds the option to assign each menu link a class in the admin UI.